# Why does Visual Studio have display lag?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I have the following problem on my MBP Pro mid 2015 16Gb RAM running Windows 10 with the latest BootCamp drivers, in Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 Community Edition.

Almost every time I alter my code Visual Studio has a significant video lag. Lines of code are messed up not showing actual code.
I've tried reinstalling Windows, cleaned up Visual Studio, no effect.

Demonstration: [screencast of the lag on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_axgYAoyBo).

Answer (score 1):

There can be many many reasons for Visual Studio being slow.

I have tried to compile an exhaustive list of possible causes,
where not all (or none) will apply to your case.
You will just have to try and see.

1. Go to **Tools -> Options → Text Editor → C# → Advanced** and uncheck **Enable full solution analysis**
2. Go to **Tools → Options → XAML Designer → General** and uncheck **Enable XAML Designer (requires restart of Visual Studio)**
3. Go to **Tools → Options → Text Editor → All Languages** and uncheck **Enable CodeLens**
4. Go to **Tools → Options → Debugging → General** and disable **Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging**
5. Go to menu **Tools** → **Options** → **Source Control** and set **Current source control …** to ***None***
6. Go to menu **Tools** → **Options** → **Environment** → **Synchronized Settings** and uncheck.
7. Clean the contents in the following cache folders (do not delete these folders, instead delete their contents only) and restart Visual Studio:

   - Clean the content in **WebSiteCache** folder (can be found in 
      *C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebSiteCache*)
   - Clean the content in **Temporary ASP.NET Files** folder (can be found in 
      *C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files*)
8. Change the scope of the `Error List` window to `Current Document`.
9. Remove the `.vs` folder from the solution folder.
10. Disabling some extension, for example ReSharper Code Inspection.
11. Disable additional displays (second or third monitor)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, and I had bad lag doing the simplest of things, it helped to update my pc drivers. The system drivers are the foundation for everything.

I was fortunate that Dell has awesome website support to do this. I let it update all the drivers it wanted to (Dell driver update is pretty much automatic).

Much of the lag seems to have gone away.